# Getting asp.net boilerplate exception: Unknown filter name: MayHaveTenant on server

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've an ASP.NET CORE web application using aspnetboilerplate.com. It works fine locally but this exception occurs in published version:

> Abp.AbpException: Unknown filter name: MayHaveTenant. Be sure this filter is registered before.

Finally this exception causes 502 error to the client:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

I'm not using multi-tenancy in this application. I see this exception recently while it was working very well before.

I tried to register MayHaveTenant filter but that was already registered. I traced failed requests but there was no useful information. Can anyone help me to solve this?

**Update**

Here is my stacktrace:

```
    Abp.AbpException: Unknown filter name: MayHaveTenant. Be sure this filter is registered before.
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.GetFilterIndex(String filterName)
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.SetFilterParameter(String filterName, String parameterName, Object value)
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.SetTenantId(Nullable`1 tenantId, Boolean switchMustHaveTenantEnableDisable)
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.Begin(UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkManager.Begin(UnitOfWorkOptions options)
   at Abp.Auditing.AuditingHelper.SaveAsync(AuditInfo auditInfo)
   at Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Auditing.AbpAuditActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at MyProject.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtTokenMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseJwtTokenMiddleware>b__0>d.MoveNext() in H:\MyProject\src\MyProject.Web.Core\Authentication\JwtBearer\JwtTokenMiddleware.cs:line 22
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

and here is my DbContext:

```
    public class MyProjectDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, MyProjectDbContext>
{
    /* Define a DbSet for each entity of the application */
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductProperty> ProductProperties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductPicture> ProductPictures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Score> Scores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }

    public MyProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyProjectDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StockConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the exception stacktrace for the error

Comment: show your DbContext

Answer (score 2):

For me, this error came after deployment of asp.net core boiler plate project into different server.

There was problem in connection string. Thanks to this misleading error, I wasted my few hours and eventually fixed it. If anyone also get such error. make sure to check connection string first. Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. We have multiple connection strings and the "Default" one was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Occurs if you have overrided OnModelCreating or Initialize method of your DbContext and not called base method.